# What is the format of the syntax tables in Apple II Integer BASIC?

Tags: apple-ii, basic, disassembly

In [Paul Santa-Maria's disassembly of Integer BASIC](http://www.callapple.org/docs/ap2/special/integerbasic.pdf) ([text version](http://www.easy68k.com/paulrsm/6502/INTLST.TXT)), you can see the syntax table split into two parts, `SYNTABL` and `SYNTABL2`. I've seen references to the tokens being stored in reverse order, and indeed, the characters within a token are in reverse order, and the tokens themselves are counted down from the ends of the tables.

What is the exact format of the syntax tables? There are a bunch of extra bytes littered around, I believe to store different versions of tokens (eg. PRINT, PRINT <string>, PRINT <expression>), and some of the tokens lack extra bytes: some of them use char+32 vs char-32 to signal the first character, but again, some don't. And some that do also have extra bytes. In addition, `SYNTABL2` ends with some extra bytes (are they usually skipped?) and `SYNTABL` starts with some apparently unused tokens, then some extra bytes of its own.

Is there a clear description somewhere?

*Context: I started out looking at the code because I'm trying to follow the exact rules for adding whitespace when rendering Integer BASIC listings to text. But now I'm intrigued.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an interesting thread here: http://forum.6502.org/viewtopic.php?t=2037

> The syntax table is in reverse order, as you've already noticed. An
>   underscore is stored at the end of the line by the line input routine.
>
> There are 32 categories (well, that's what I'm going to call them).
>   Each category contains one or more rules.
>
> The syntax tokens are:
>
> ```
> $00: return with syntax error
> $01: return with no error
> $02: parse a comment character (any non-control character, stops at the end of the line)
> $03: parse a string literal character (stops at a closing quote)
> $04-$1F: categories $04-$1F, next token is required
> $20-$3F: categories $00-$1F, next token (and beyond) is optional
> $40-$5F: categories $00-$1F, end of category
> $60-$7D: categories $00-$1D, end of rule
> $7E: branch "backward" 2 bytes
> $7F: branch "backward" 1 byte
> $80: parse letter A-Z, next token is required
> $81: parse number 0-9, next token is required
> $82-$BF: parse character "-_ -- next token is required
> $C0: parse letter A-Z, end of rule
> $C1: parse number 0-9, end of rule
> $C2-$FF: parse character "-_ -- end of rule
> ```
>
> The category table (SYNTABLNDX in the linked listing) is at $E197. To
>   address 512 bytes with 8 bits, each category starts at an odd address.
>   Each entry in the category table is:
>
> `DB (ADDRESS_OF_START_OF_CATEGORY-1)/2`
>
> Category $07 is a numeric expression. So HLIN $07 AT $07 , $67 means
>   HLIN  AT  ,  and the $67 indicates the
>   end of the HLIN rule.
>
> Category $00 is an unsigned number (line number), so LIST $20 , $60
>   (at $EC61) means the LIST  ,  with the comma
>   and the second line number optional
>
> Category $19 is a numberic variable name, so NEXT $39 , $7E means NEXT
>    ,  , ... i.e. NEXT A or NEXT A,B or NEXT A,B,C
>   etc.
>
> Sometimes keywords are duplicated to force a mismatch (and thus force
>   the end of a category). For example, RNDX (at $ED69) can never be
>   matched since it comes after RND (at $ED75) in the numeric function
>   category (at $ED79). (The first three letters would match RND first.)
>   Thus, RNDX matches nothing and effectively marks the end of the
>   category.
>
> If you're curious about the THEN TO STEP etc. keywords at $EC17, see
>   this thread:
>
> viewtopic.php?t=726
>
> If you have further questions, feel free to ask.